# How to merge an external DocuSign envelope with a SpringCM workflow?

Tags: docusignapi

In SpringCM worklfows the norm is to place a document/contract in a DocuSign envelope which can then be sent to the other party and completed in your own organisation. Some counter parties have their own DocuSign based flow and may want to initiate the workflow. Is there a way to merge the externally started envelope in your own organisations workflow?

Answer (score -1):

For SpringCM workflows we recommend opening a case directly with us. You can open a support case here:  http://support.docusign.com/

Note: I am part of DocuSign support

Comment: It is advisable to add such answers as comments.